# Moving Product Meta to Additional Information Tab

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I need to move the Product Meta content from under the "Add to Cart" button to the "Additional Information" Tab, I want it to display similar to the attribute as the client wants to move this information to Additional Information Tab.

For eg - http://yellowbee.online/product/yellow-bee-aqua-bug-led-clogs/

I need to move the "SKU", "Categories" and "Tags" to the tab which says "Additional Information"

Website is made using xStore Theme on Wordpress & Woocommerce, I have tried reading a lot on how to achieve this but all attempts have failed.

I have tried adding the following code to the functions.php in the child theme. No Luck.

```
function additional_product_tabs_metabox()
{
    add_meta_box(
        'add_product_metabox_additional_tabs',
        __( 'Additional product Tabs', 'woocommerce' ),
        'additional_product_tabs_metabox_content',
        'product',
        'normal',
        'high'
    );
}
```

I am hoping that someone has a solution on the right code to to get this hook and then to display it in the additional information tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the following:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 10 );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

> This will work if the related hooks are not yet customized by the theme or a plugin.

Comment: Is this still working? I've tested it on my website and it's not. Maybe the last WooCommerce updates changed something?

Comment: EDIT: It works in adding the Product Meta in the Additional Information tab but not in removing it from the Product Summary. Therefore is almost certainly an issue depending on customization from my theme or some plugin. Thank you.

Comment: @Marco This code still perfectly work on most themes (that doesn't have related customizations). Tested and works on last woocommerce version under Storefront theme.

Comment: Works with Avada Theme and Product Code for WooCommerce plug in.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
    $tabs['delivery_information'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Additional information', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 16,
        'callback'  => 'product_additional_info_tab'
    );
   return $tabs;
}

function product_additional_info_tab() {
    $info = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 
   'additional_product_tabs_metabox_content', true);
    echo $info;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, I added this to the Child Theme's function.php file and all it did was create a new tab which says "Additional Information" and its blank :(

Comment: Looks that not working only tab content part, i never used metaboxes, so problem can be ger_post_meta can you fifured out that bit yourself?